# Acces to a Text Field from another class

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, private

I'm working now on a mini project and I find some difficulties. Indeed, I have a class Jframe "InterfaceConnexion" where you enter a Username and Password, after having a clicked a JButton Enter, you reach a new Jframe "InterfaceClient". In the latter I wish get all the informations related to that "username" (I am connected to a database).
I thought about using the "Username" and "Password" entered by the user  but I can not because the TextField are private by default, so impossible to have the username and password entered in the textfield from another class.
I hope I was clear enough in setting out my problem.
thank you

Comment: Please provide some code because what you're describing is hard to understand. From what I read, it seems like you're trying to access a private Textfield from another class?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. it's really hard to debug code when all we have is a verbal description. Please edit your question and copy in all relevant sections of code. If you have error messages and log-files paste the relevant sections of those too (only the relevant sections). All the information you can. Best yet - read this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Two things, 1: provide a getter of some kind to expose the field via the class; 2: Provide a reference to the object to the other class through which you can call the getter; 3: Don't expose UI components via public getters, instead, consider providing a getter to get the value of the field instead (and a setter if required)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Username and Password JTextFields are contained within "InterfaceConnexion" (incorrect spelling by the way), you should create getter methods with less restrictive access modifiers (eg. public or protected) for both of the the text fields.

You may also wish to consider using a [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) instead, for password input.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with `JTextField`, I like to code using this method because it saves me head aches and I usually like this preferred way because its pretty simple and can be a single line of code for each.

```
   String username = usernameFld.getText();
   String password = passwordFld.getText();
```